# Webpack module federation

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

Im trying to configure a simple module federation as shown below.

**webpack.config1**

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "Picture",
        filename: "entryPoint.js",
        exposes: {
          "./Gallery": "./mySrc/components/Gallery.js",
        },
      }),
```

**index.js**

```
import("Picture/Gallery").then((comp) => {
  console.log(comp);
});
```

**Gallery.js**

```
export default 3;
```

**webpack.config2**

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: "Consumer",
    filename: "entryPoint.js",
    remotes: {
      Picture: "Gallery@http://localhost:3000/entryPoint.js",
    },
  }),
```

I get this message:

> entryPoint.js":1 Uncaught (in promise) ScriptExternalLoadError:
> Loading script failed. (missing: http://localhost:3000/entryPoint.js)
> while loading "./Gallery" from webpack/container/reference/Picture
> at Object.webpack/container/reference/Picture (entryPoint.js":1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24)
> at handleFunction (remotes loading:33)
> at remotes loading:52
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Object.**webpack_require**.f.remotes (remotes loading:15)
> at ensure chunk:6
> at Array.reduce ()
> at Function.**webpack_require**.e (ensure chunk:5)
> at Function.fn.e (hot module replacement:81)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import in your `webpack.config2` seems to be wrong. In `webpack.config1` you defined your app under the name Picture. So `webpack.config2` should look like this:

```js
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "Consumer",
  filename: "entryPoint.js",
  remotes: {
    Picture: "Picture@http://localhost:3000/entryPoint.js",
  },
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification has been done in the latest angular-cli/webpack,

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "Consumer",
  filename: "entryPoint.js",
  remotes: {
    Picture: "http://localhost:3000/entryPoint.js",
  },
}),
```

Picture need not be given before the js meta information URL.